# How to add command to Unreal Commander context menu

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I don't have 7-zip context menu entry in Unreal Commander, and I'd like to add it.
Is this setup from registry editor or somewhere else?

Comment: I am wondering this too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a 64-bit OS, and Unreal Commander is a 32-bit app, make sure you install the 32-bit version of 7-zip in addition to the 64-bit one.

Its good way to install both versions 7-zip's if you want to work also with other 64-bit file managers.